# how to create win32 smart device project

Tags: silverlight, embedded, for-loop

hi
i need to develop silverlight application for windows embedded.as i referred some links silverlight for windows embedded supports only native code(C++). for this i build my silverlight application in blend2 and i converted that xaml file into c++ files using XAML2CPP. and now im trying to create win32 smart device project using VS2008 but for that im not getting which option we have to select and how to do can anyone of help me

Comment: Wow. I thought you had to be messed up, but it appears you are right. Doesn't seem like silverlight really, but.... Do you have the Silverlight Embedded tools installed? http://www.uxmagic.com/blog/?tag=/Windows+Embedded+Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this can be done in two ways:

1. You can use a SDK provided by the OEM of your device, then create a Smart Device Project based on this SDK, then you can start the development of your Silverlight C++ project.
2. If you are the OEM of the device (it means, you have a BSP and you configure and generate the OS images and SDKs). Then you can create a subproject of your OS design and even include your application as part of your OS image, or you could just generate a new SDK and use option 1.